# Bootstrap, match rows' height with window height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have this very simple code:

```html
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: grey;">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: green;">
      <br>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

Which gives this picture:

[image]

How do you fill the rest of the window (red square) with the color yellow (second row) and push the last row to the bottom of the page ?

Thank you

Comment: @XYZ Nearly, but the yellow part is a bit to big and I have to scroll to see the green row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox...

https://www.codeply.com/go/eXvFDheMxT

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow {
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

And, in the upcoming Bootstrap 4, no additional CSS is needed.

https://www.codeply.com/go/sNvNLAiCki

Answer (score 1):

Try using a footer and setting the min-height of the container to 100%?

Example CSS

```
min-height: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
margin: 0 auto -33px;
```

Comment: Thanks, but to which rows do I apply your CSS code ?

Comment: Have a look at this example on Bootstrap.  Think this layout will help as it has a fixed header and footer.  The container would then have the CSS from the answer http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.class1 {
    flex-grow:1;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="background-color: grey;">
    <br>
</div>
<div class="row class1">
  <br>
</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color: green;">
  <br>
</div>    
</div>
```